# Move UIScrollView when keyboard comes into place

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, keyboard

[Edit:] The problem has been solved.  I did not have my delegates linked properly in `UIBuilder`.  Code is good!

I am trying to resize a scrollview when the keyboard appears.   I went to the developer docs and found this information.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1

On the left "Managing the keyboard".

In the documentation it shows a bit of code to detect the size of the keyboard and then to resize a `UIScrollView`.  I have placed an `NSLog` message in the code for function `- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification` so I see that the function is actually being called, but when I try to to `NSLog` the `kbSize`.height it is always valued at 0.

Why does the code that apple provide for this purpose not work?

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that snippet of code contains everything I needed :)

Comment: You could use [KBKeyboardObserver](https://github.com/kam800/KBKeyboardObserver) library to observe keyboard events.

Answer (score 33):

You may want to try the highly recommended "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView", available from: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Works like a charm...

Comment: +1 Easy as hell  to implement and really good. I suggest combining it with the BSKeyboardControl to add navigation control in the textfields: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bskeyboardcontrols

Comment: @Reuven When using TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollview, Sometimes if we copy and paste in textview the view entirely goes up,.. is there any solution for that?..

Comment: Does it work with `UIPresentationModeFormSheet` though?

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever added an observer for that specific notification? Make sure that in your `loadView` method you do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

Don't forget to unregister the observer on `viewDidUnload` method like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Let me know if that works out!

Comment: I did add the observers, as I mentioned I can see the function is called when the keyboard shows, so I do know that the observer is working.  Thanks though always good to double check things,

Comment: You need to update this post. viewDidUnload is no longer called.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this several times with a `UITableView` (which is just an extended `UIScrollView`). You can find the [code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209499/avoid-view-when-opening-keyboard-from-a-uitextview-inside-a-uitableview-with-cus/8216672#8216672).

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to add the extension UIViewController+Keyboard.swift to your project, with a single line

```
setupKeyboardNotifcationListenerForScrollView(scrollView)
```

it will auto resize automatically when keyboard appears. No need to subclass anything, just an extension! Its availble at GitHub [SingleLineKeyboardResize](https://github.com/haaakon/SingleLineKeyboardResize)